# How to handle locations when a country does not have postal codes?

Tags: java, angularjs, scala, twitter-bootstrap, elasticsearch

I am working on a project to crowdsource demographic data.

Once of the key bits of information for any demographic dataset would be postal code, and I've seen lots of things online to help me automatically detect the country, and allow the user to enter their appropriate postal code to set their location. GeoNames, Zippopotum.us, etc.

My struggle is, not every country **has** postal codes.

Is there a resource out there that allows the user to pick from a dropdown of cities if they're in a country that doesn't support postal codes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GeoNames data to implement this.  GeoNames provides data dumps containing city information:

```
cities1000.zip           : all cities with a population > 1000 or seats of adm div (ca 80.000)
cities5000.zip           : all cities with a population > 5000 or PPLA (ca 40.000)
cities15000.zip          : all cities with a population > 15000 or capitals (ca 20.000)
```

You can download these from http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/ and read more about them on http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/readme.txt

You'll get a tab-delimited text file in utf8 encoding, with one row per city.  Each row has name, latitude, longitude, and country code, plus additional fields described in the readme.txt.

This is a simple flat file, so there's all sorts of ways you could incorporate it into your application.  Since you tagged this question with elasticsearch, you may want to index this data in an Elasticsearch index.  Then you could get a list of cities by searching for country, state/region (admin1 code), or by proximity to a latitude/longitude (see http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/geo-location-and-search/).

Comment: Thank you! I'll look at implementing this way and come back with results!

Comment: By the way, if anyone wants to check it out, the project is www.statly.net . Its ElasticSearch / Scala / Angular JS / Twitter-Bootstrap.